# IKImageBrowserView Grouping Issue

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to group images in `ImageBrowserView` with take date but have some weird problem.

If there are two or less groups everything looks fine

[image]

But if I add more pictures and group number increases view gets completely messed up

[image]

Here is my `datasource` code:

```
List<BrowseItem> images = new List<BrowseItem> ();

    public List<DateTime> DateGroup 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return images.Select(x => x.ImageTakeDate.Date).Distinct().ToList(); 
        } 
    }


    public override nint GroupCount(IKImageBrowserView aBrowser)
    {
        return DateGroup.Count;
    }

    public override NSDictionary GetGroup(IKImageBrowserView aBrowser, nint index)
    {
        var dateHeader = DateGroup[(int)index];
        NSRange r = new NSRange(0, images.Count(x => x.ImageTakeDate.Date == dateHeader.Date));

        var keys = new string[] { GroupRangeKey, GroupTitleKey, GroupStyleKey };
        var objs = new NSObject[] { NSValue.FromRange(r), new NSString(dateHeader.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy, dddd")), NSNumber.FromNInt((int)IKGroupStyle.Disclosure) };

        return NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(objs, keys);
    }

    public override nint ItemCount (IKImageBrowserView aBrowser)
    {
        return images.Count;
    }

    public override IIKImageBrowserItem GetItem (IKImageBrowserView aBrowser, nint index)
    {
        return images [(int)index];
    }
```

Any ideas what's wrong with the view?